# Showing $\{(x,y,z):0\le x<1, y^2+z^2\le 1\}$ is neither open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Would it be correct to argue as follows:

$A=\{(x,y,z):0\le x<1, y^2+z^2\le 1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is neither open nor closed because $H=\{0,y,z\}:y^2+z^2\le 1\}\subset A$ is closed since $\nexists\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset A$ for any $x\in H$. But $J=A\backslash H$ is open since for any $\vec{x}\in J$, $\delta := 1-\Vert \vec{x}-proj_{\imath}(\vec{x})\Vert$, $B_\delta(\vec{x})\in J$. Therefore, A is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Hello. I don't quite understand your argument. It looks like you have a subset $H\subset A$ of $A$ that you argue is closed. How does this imply that $A$ is neither open nor closed?

Comment: I'm also saying that $J$ is open.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to find a point in $A$ such that no open ball containing that point lies wholly within $A$, so that $A$ is not open?  And then show that there is a point not in $A$ that nevertheless is the limit of a sequence of points in $A$, so that $A$ is not closed?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand where you are going with that. You seem to want to argue that $H$ is closed in $A$, and its complement is open. But what does this say about $A$? Also, you don't actually prove that $H$ is closed in $A$, but you prove that it is not open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way to see this is to note that the set is a solid cylinder that includes one cap (at $x=0$) but not the other (at $x=1$). An open $X$ set in Euclidean space is one such that for any $x\in X$ and any $\epsilon>0$, if $\|y-x\|<\epsilon$, then $y\in X$. This is not true at $x=0$, so the set is not open. A closed set in Euclidean space is one that contains all its limit points. This fails at $x=1$, since, for instance, the limit of the sequence $(1-1/n,0,0)_{n=1,2,3,\ldots}$ is the point $(1,0,0)$, which is not included in the set. Therefore the set is not closed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I drew a portrait of the set and approached it  heuristically, but rigorous approach is more difficult, especially considering that the part about limit points has not been covered yet.

Comment: The rigorous bit comes with knowing definitions and things. If you're drawing these pictures, you're on the right track! That's often the best way to start in my experience.